# Is there a way I can implement a custom route so that certain route values are automatically passed?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, multi-tenant

I have an application that is multitenant, that is, I have multiple clients that use the application and share a single domain using folders. Like the following:

1. www.mydomain.com/`client1`/home/index
2. www.mydomain.com/`client2`/home/index

I can't use areas because the clients are not static, they register and they must be able to start using the application right away. I can't use subdomains because in this case I don't have dynamic control over the DNS.

That being said, how can I implement a custom route so that I don't need to pass the client name every time I build an outgoing URL?

That is, I want this to be true:

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Home") -> www.mydomain.com/client1/home/index
```

without passing `client1`, something can resolve `client1` because by the time I build this URL, this string will be a value of the current route values, because I'm already at the `client1`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{client}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Now when you navigate to `/client1/Home/Index`  and if inside the `Index.cshtml` view when you use:

```
@Html.ActionLink("foo", "About")
```

this will generate:

```
<a href="/client1/home/About">foo</a>
```

Same stands true for using the `Url.Action` helper inside the `Index` action. It will preserve the `client` route value from the original request.